# MongoDB update function doesn't work with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to insert a new field into a document in MongoDB, but the database has no changes after my query.
This is the single element of my database:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a9f5f4bb9ba6117b5551f7d"),
"userId" : "user123",
"name" : "Device zm3",
"category" : [
    "pm10",
    "pm25",
    "temperature"
],
"__v" : 0}
```

I want to have something like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a9f5f4bb9ba6117b5551f7d"),
"userId" : "user123",
"name" : "Device zm3",
"category" : [
    "pm10",
    "pm25",
    "temperature"
],
"data": 5
"__v" : 0}
```

I use this query:

```
Device.update({
        'userId': 'user123'
      }, {
        $set: {
          'data': 5
        }
      }, {
        upsert: true,
      }
```

I was trying with fields witch already exists in database such as "name" or "category", and in this case solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to add a field with Mongoose, it should also be in your Mongoose schema. So you would have to add "data" to your Device schema if you want to use Mongoose. That's why fields already in the object/schema (like "name" or "category") work but new ones don't.